# Excel VBA - Evaluate-Match with three criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the following code to:

- use three factors (Factor A, Factor B, and Factor C) from a worksheet in a workbook (mysheet an mybook respcetively),
- to search over a data set in a worksheet in a second workbook (sourcesheet and sourcebook),
- and return an index that corresponds to the row of data in the sourcesheet data which matches the three factors from mysheet.

The index is returned to variant v, which should return error code 2042 if no row is found that matches the three critera.

I have extracted the code from my larger subfuction, and simplified it to be non-specific.

```
Sub enter_data()

Dim mybook As Workbook, sourcebook As Workbook
Dim mysheet As Worksheet, sourcesheet As Worksheet
Dim FactorA$, FactorB$, FactorC$
Dim i%
Dim v As Variant

'set names for workbooks and worksheets
Set mybook = Workbooks("mydatabook.xlsm")
Set mysheet = mybook.Sheets("mydatasheet")
Set sourcebook = Workbooks("sourcedatasbook.xlsm")
Set sourcesheet = sourcebook.Sheets("sourcedatasheet")

'i is incremented and used to go through every line of data I want to extract from -
'I have only included one instance of i for this example 

i = 3

'create names for search factors
FactorA = "'[" & mybook.Name & "]" & mysheet.Name & "'!" & mysheet.Cells(i, 1).Address(False, False)
FactorB = "'[" & mybook.Name & "]" & mysheet.Name & "'!" & mysheet.Cells(i, 6).Address(False, False)
FactorC = "'[" & mybook.Name & "]" & mysheet.Name & "'!" & mysheet.Cells(i, 3).Address(False, False)
Debug.Print "     FactorA: " & FactorA, vbCrLf & _
            "     FactorB: " & FactorB, vbCrLf & _
            "     FactorC: " & FactorC, vbCrLf

'search for data

'two factor search
v = sourcesheet.Evaluate("MATCH(" & FactorA & "&" & FactorB & "&" & FactorC & ", G6:G6000&C6:C6000&D6:D6000, 0)")
Debug.Print v

'three factor search
v = sourcesheet.Evaluate("MATCH(" & FactorA & "&" & FactorB & ", G6:G6000&C6:C6000, 0)")
Debug.Print v

'three factor search using explicit references (this was copied almost directly from a cell in excel
v = sourcesheet.Evaluate("MATCH('[mydatabook.xlsm]mydatasheet'!A3&'[mydatabook.xlsm]mydatasheet'!F3&'[mydatabook.xlsm]mydatasheet'!C3, C6:C6000&D6:D6000&G6:G6000, 0)")
Debug.Print v

End Sub
```

The columns of the table I'm using look like:

**mybook.mysheet:**

Factor A    Column B    Factor C    Column D    Column E    Factor B

**sourcebook.sourcesheet:**

Column A    Column B    Factor B    Factor C    Column E    Column F    Factor A

Currently:

- on the first debug.print v, I get an index if a row exists, or an error 2042 if it does not
- on the second debug.print v, I always get an error 2015
- on the third debug.print v, I always get an error 2015

The function in the third debug.print was directly copied from a cell in excel, where it either returns an index or an #N/A

Is there any reason why the second and third debug.print doesn't ever return an index or error 2042 like it should?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Whenever I see `Evaluate` and a `WorksheetFunction` in VBA code I am wondering why VBA is used and not the functions directly in the Excel sheet. Yet, if you are willing to use VBA then why don't you rather make use of two-dimensional arrays: (1) get the ranges in arrays, (2) do the comparison yourself, (3) return one or more matche(s)?

Comment: The reason I'm using VBA rather than the function directly in the excel sheet is that the data I'm searching for is on a second workbook that will not always be accessible. Will I be able to show the data values I've pulled after the second workbook is inaccessible? If I can still display the data, I would strongly prefer to use the function directly in the excel sheet. 

As for the second point, I simply don't know how! I will look up the method you've suggested, and see if I can do it myself.

Comment: Even when you are implementing VBA you will need to have access to the file. But to make your file work (even when no access to the other file is available) you could create a hidden sheet in your Excel file and copy all relevant data in there. Then you can use VBA or workhseet functions.

Comment: When I'm using VBA, the data I need is placed into my cells as values, while when I use the formula in the cell, cell references to the other workbook are broken when access to the source sheet in broken. Is this correct? I am relatively new to higher level excel. Unfortunately, I cannot copy all of the source data into my sheet and hide the sheet due to a security policy on the source sheet. All i can copy is the exact data I need.

Comment: (1) Yes, you are correct. (2) No need to copy **all** data. Just **relevant** data which you need for VBA or worksheet functions alike (as written above). (3) If you link in an Excel file data to another file then the formula **and** the value are stored (so there is no need to open the linked file each time). When you open a file with links you get the choice to update the links or work with the old (stored) values. Still, I am failing to see what you are trying to tell me with your comment or what your train of thought is. My above comment prevails: use worksheet functions or arrays in VBA.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use arrays